# What is the role of から in this case?

Tags: grammar, particle-から

The whole sentence is:

> [布]{ぬの}はたくさんの[人]{ひと}から[人気]{にんき}があって、いつも[高]{たか}く[売]{う}れました。

Source: https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-lessons/3-4-the-crane-of-gratitude/

In my best understanding, it sounds: "Because there are many people [buy?] the cloth, it gains popularity and always sold at a high price.". But I feel something wrong in this translation...

Answer (score 2):

Judging by this https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/102295, から　can be used to link 人気　to  たくさんの人 - popular **with** many people, although it seems it's not the most common method.
So, it's "cloth was popular with many people (and) he could etc"

Comment: Thank you very much!